Not able to fill the password input field using playwright javascript which has readonly attribute
Using the CSS locator with the ID, attempt to fill in the password field during registration. The password field has attributes type=password, readonly, and autocomplete=off.
HTML of the password field:
<div class="form-item RegistrationForm_password">
<label for="RegistrationForm_password" class="form-label"><span class="form-label-text">Password</span><span class="required-field">*</span></label><div class="form-field">
 <span class="password-visibility-icon icon-hide"></span>
<input type="password" id="RegistrationForm_password" name="RegistrationForm[password]" placeholder="" autocomplete="off" class="form-field-element" readonly="readonly"></div></div>


await page.locator("//input[@id='RegistrationForm_password']").fill("Password")

Error:

locator.fill: Test timeout of 30000ms exceeded.

Call log:

waiting for locator('//input[@id='RegistrationForm_password']')
locator resolved to <input placeholder="" type="password" autocomplete="off…/>
fill("Testing1")
attempting fill action
waiting for element to be visible, enabled and editable
element is not editable
retrying fill action, attempt #1
waiting for element to be visible, enabled and editable
element is not editable

Can anyone please provide me the solution?
It is working in Selenium but not in playwright

This is the expected behavior. Read only means you can't fill it. The solution is to find a way through the UI to enable editing that field so you can fill it, or don't attempt to fill it when it's impossible to do so as a user. Or set the value by force with JS with element.value = "foobar", which is fine in scraping (assuming you don't need event handlers to fire) but not in testing. BTW, don't use xpath, especially if you're testing.

As long as the element has the readonly="readonly" attribute, you cannot fill it correctly. Playwright looks at page elements just like a real user. If you need this particular line of code not to fail with an error, then you can use the force option in the fill method: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-fill-option-force
await page.locator("//input[@id='RegistrationForm_password']").fill("Password", { force: true});

